# Need to add string text below each bar in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am generating some  visual reports using  MpAndroidChart  specifically  bar-chart the thing is I need below  each  bar instead of their value having a string  value of months i.e. like this (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc...)  I can't figure it out tried everything. below is a screenshot for demonstration.[image]

Here  is my Kotlin  Code:

```
class ReportsFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = ReportsFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: ReportsViewModel
    private lateinit var binding:FragmentReportsBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentReportsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ReportsViewModel::class.java)
       

        val  barDataSet =  BarDataSet(getDataValues(), "Data Set 01")
        val barData = BarData()
        barDataSet.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), com.flexymint.resource.R.color.blue_700))

        barData.addDataSet(barDataSet)

        binding.expenseBarChart.data = barData
        binding.expenseBarChart.invalidate()

    }

    private fun getDataValues () : ArrayList<BarEntry> {
        val dataValues:ArrayList<BarEntry>  = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
        
        dataValues.add(BarEntry(2F, 15F))
        dataValues.add(BarEntry(3F, 9F))
        dataValues.add(BarEntry(4F, 12F))
        dataValues.add(BarEntry(5F, 14F))
        dataValues.add(BarEntry(6F, 12F))
        dataValues.add(BarEntry(7F, 18F))
        dataValues.add(BarEntry(8F, 16F))
        dataValues.add(BarEntry(9F, 11F))
        dataValues.add(BarEntry(10F, 8F))
        dataValues.add(BarEntry(11F, 22F))
        dataValues.add(BarEntry(12F, 29F))
        return dataValues
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the label_name and barDataSet in BarData constructor.

```
  val  barDataSet =  BarDataSet(getDataValues(), "Data Set 01")
  val labels = ArrayList<String>()
  labels.add("labels1")
  labels.add("labels2")
  val barData = BarData(labels, barDataSet)
```

Comment: I think doesn’t work! there is no available constructor for labels. any idea?

Comment: My library version is: MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0.

Comment: No this string jan,feb store in an arrayList and pass through BarData constructor that you have already.

Comment: I am saying there is no constructor available I checked your code android studio cant detect any constructor like yours maybe that is deprecated